# Programa fecha ao tentar apagar primeiro elemento de uma lista encadeada sem header

Tags: c, ponteiro, lista-encadeada

Tenho que criar um programa para controle de um estacionamento utilizando uma lista encadeada simples, o programa está funcionando bem, exceto por um problema, quando tento excluir o primeiro elemento da lista o programa fecha e mostra a seguinte mensagem:
"Process exited after 31.55 seconds with return value 3221225477".
Por ser uma atividade de faculdade há diversas restrições que dificultam a criação do programa, pois eu poderia simplesmente criar um header como primeiro elemento, mas como não é o caso como eu poderia excluir o primeiro elemento sem ocasionar um erro no programa e após isso transformar o segundo elemento no primeiro?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

struct veiculo{
    char modelo[20];
    char placa[7];
    veiculo *prox;
};

veiculo *prim,*ult,*ant;

void inserir(){
    if(prim==NULL){
        prim = new(veiculo);
        ult = prim;
    }else{
        ult ->prox = new(veiculo);
        ult = ult->prox;
    }
    cout<<"Informe o modelo do veiculo:"<<endl;
    cin>>ult->modelo;
    cout<<"Informe a placa do veiculo:"<<endl;
    cin>>ult->placa;
    ult->prox=NULL;
}

veiculo *pesquisarant(char placa[7]){
    veiculo*aux = prim;
    veiculo*ant = NULL;
    while(aux!=NULL){
        if(strcmp(aux->placa,placa)==0){   
            return ant;
        }
        ant = aux;
        aux = aux->prox;}
    return ant;
    }
    
void remover(veiculo *ant){
    veiculo *aux;
    if(ant!=NULL){
        aux=ant->prox;
        ant->prox=aux->prox;
    }else{
        aux=prim;
        prim = prim->prox;
    }
    delete(aux);
}

void listar(){
    veiculo *aux = prim;
    while(aux!=NULL){
        cout<<"Modelo do veiculo:"<<aux->modelo<<endl<<"Placa do veiculo:"<<aux->placa<<endl<<endl;
        aux = aux->prox;
    }
}

void print(){
    cout<<prim->prox;
}


int main(){
    prim = ult = NULL;
    int op = 0;
    char placa[7];
    while(op<4){
        cout<<"Selecione uma opcao:"<<endl<<"1-Inserir veiculo"<<endl<<"2-Excluir veiculo por placa"<<endl<<"3-Listar todos os veiculos"<<endl<<"4-Sair do programa."<<endl;
        cin>>op;
        switch(op){
            case 1:
                inserir();
                break;
            case 2:
                cout<<"Informe a placa do veiculo"<<endl;
                cin>>placa;
                ant = pesquisarant(placa);
                if(ant->prox==NULL){
                    cout<<"Veiculo nao encontrado."<<endl;
                }else{
                    remover(ant);
                    cout<<"Veiculo removido."<<endl;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                listar();
                break;
            case 4:
                cout<<"Programa encerrado.";
                break;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Esse é praticamente um programa em `C` e é um desperdício escrever assim em `C++`.  Listas com ponteiro para um lado só são muito mais complicadas do que as que tem ponteiros para os dois lados. E entenda que a lista NÃO é de `veiculo` por exemplo. A lista é de nós e cada nó deve conter ou apontar para um `veiculo` nesse caso. Não escrever o programa assim só vai te dar muito mais trabalho e mais dificuldade em usar isso em outros programas.

Comment: A remoção do primeiro valor teoricamente tera que apontar para o segundo endereço de memória mas ao fazer isso vai tratar o programa, o problema sera na memoria pois o primeiro se perdeu assim causando a paralisação do programa. para evitar tera fazer uma verificação antes se o valor é NULL antes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> programa para controle de um estacionamento utilizando uma lista encadeada simples, o programa está funcionando bem, exceto por um problema

Então em resumo o programa não está funcionando.

Porque não consegue excluir o primeiro?
A lógica está errada:

```
                cout << "Informe a placa do veiculo"
                     << endl;
                cin >> placa;
                ant = pesquisarant(placa);
```

Então você vai lá pesquisar e retorna o endereço do anterior... e lá está:

```
        if (strcmp(aux->placa, placa) == 0) { return ant; }
```

Só que se for remover o primeiro não tem anterior e então como você escreveu retorna `ant` que é `NULL` porque antes do primeiro não tem ninguém, por definição de primeiro.

E aí você tenta

```
                ant = pesquisarant(placa);
                if (ant->prox == NULL)
```

Claro que se `ant` é `NULL` não pode acessar algo como `ant->prox` e aí seu programa cancela.

Seu programa não está nada bom. Vai ter um trabalho do inferno para terminar assim.

Vou repetir o que comentei:

Esse é praticamente um programa em C e é um desperdício escrever assim em C++. Listas com ponteiro para um lado só são muito mais complicadas do que as que tem ponteiros para os dois lados. E entenda que a lista NÃO é de veiculo por exemplo. A lista é de nós e cada nó deve conter ou apontar para um veiculo nesse caso. Não escrever o programa assim só vai te dar muito mais trabalho e mais dificuldade em usar isso em outros programas.

Seu programa só funciona para 1 lista e tem nada menos que 3 ponteiros globais para uma única lista. Mais tarde se der tempo eu mostro uma outra maneira de escrever isso.

De todo modo tem sua resposta: seu programa cancela porque o primeiro elemento não tem antecessor para você achar o próximo.

Adicionar um header não seria uma solução. Em geral esse registro é chamado de sentinela em português --- *sentinel* --- e não header. Mas não precisa disso.

Comment: Realmente já vi formas melhores de fazer a lista encadeada, porém como o professor está no começo da matéria e está nos ensinando desse jeito resolvi fazer dessa forma, mas já estou aprendendo a melhorar o código, entretanto sua resposta resolveu meu problema, obrigado, conseguir consertar o código dessa forma `if(ant==ult or prim ==NULL){cout<<"Placa nao encontrada"<<endl}` como o elemento anterior é o ultimo quer dizer que nao achou a placa informada, nao tinha pensado dessa forma e como sou iniciante em ponteiros não sabia dessa regra sobre apontar um elemento NULL para NULL.

Comment: Não sei o que seria essa regra de apontar `NULL` para `NULL`. Se tem relação ao erro original não é uma regra: apenas não tem sentido escrever `NULL->prox`

Comment: Então minha resposta, que responde diretamente a pergunta e tem uma explicação de onde e porque o programa cancela é marcada como inútil já no primeiro dia. E por ao menos dois diligentes usuários! Genial. Preciso mesmo melhorar minhas respostas! E não é que o autor da pergunta achou que era uma resposta de fato e a marcou com tal? E escreveu um comentário a respeito? Continuarei tentando melhorar! Ou não.